# Why does i cant bind the datasource to my datagridview with result from stored procedure?

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures, datagridview

My SP :
[image]

My C#:
[image]

I can't get method `.ToList()` in `eksekusi` for datasource in datagridview, how to solve this?

Comment: Please provide actual code and not pictures of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the stored procedure is a collection of items (`IEnumerable<T>`/`IQueryable<T>`). When you perform `FirstOrDefault` you retrieve the first item in the collection or `default(T)` if collection is empty.

The `T` that you have is not an `IEnumerable<T>` but an object representing a single record with 3 properties, so you do not have the `ToList()` extension method.

Comment: @Student - Good :) Please do edit your post to have the actual code and not pictures of it. That is the standard of how to post questions on SO

Comment: next time i will be better when posting something, thanks for the suggestion sir :)